# How to add spring interceptor only for registered mappings (endpoints)

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I have an issue related to `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`.

Interceptor:

```
@Component
public class RequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler)
        throws Exception {
        //some logic
        return true;
    }

}
```

WebMvcConfigurer

```
@Configuration
public class FsWebMvcConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String API_PATTERN = "/**/api/**/";

    private final RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor;

    @Autowired
    public FsWebMvcConfigurer(final RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor) {
        this.requestInterceptor = requestInterceptor;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(requestInterceptor).addPathPatterns(API_PATTERN);
    }
}
```

And it works as expected - every request with pattern `/**/api/**/` is getting intercepted.

Unfortunetly it also works for the endpoints that are not registered - I don't want that kind of behaviour. How can I specify that the registered interceptor should only work with registered mappings?

Note: I don't want to specify exactly every existing endpoint by myself (e.g adding all as pattern)

Comment: You can start with trying to access `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping` class since it stores all REST-mappings built on application startup. It has public method `getMappingRegistry()`